# How to use AWS Secrets Manager to store Heroku Env Vars

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, aws-secrets-manager, rbenv-vars

I have some secrets stored in AWS Secrets Manager.

How can I reference that datastore source as a Heroku Env Var?

Ideally, the envvar would update any time it is invoked.

Thanks!